# MongoDB: how to find latest comment in collection for items particular user commented on

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB of gocomics comments. Sample comment (from 
"db.comments.find().pretty()"):

`{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("518f14e5394594efbe18068c"), 
        "body" : "plan for it", 
        "commentid" : "2525923", 
        "commentor" : "Chocoloop", 
        "commentorid" : "769338", 
        "da" : "25", 
        "filename" : "/mnt/sshfs/gocomics/comments/100.out.bz2", 
        "mo" : "11", 
        "strip" : "luann", 
        "stripname" : "Luann", 
        "time" : "1 day ago", 
        "yy" : "2011" 
}`

This shows that "Chocoloop" made the comment "plan for it" on the 
2011-11-25 "Luann" strip. The commentid was 2525923, and is unique to 
this comment. The other fields aren't relevant for this question.

A single person can make multiple comments on the same strip. For 
example, "Chocoloop" may've made a later comment on the 2011-11-25 
"Luann" strip. The later comment would have the same strip, da, mo, 
yr, commentor fields, but a higher commentid.

I want to find the latest comment I've made on each strip. This is easy:

`db.comments.aggregate( 
{$match: {commentor:"barrycarter"}}, 
{$group: {_id: {strip: "$strip", yy: "$yy", da:"$da", mo:"$mo"}, 
 mid: {$max:"$commentid"}}} 
)`

Here is one of many results:

`{ 
                        "_id" : { 
                                "strip" : "pearlsbeforeswine", 
                                "yy" : "2007", 
                                "da" : "28", 
                                "mo" : "11" 
                        }, 
                        "mid" : "2462203" 
                }`

This says I made at least one comment (perhaps several) on the 
pearlsbeforeswine strip dated 2007-11-28. Of the comments I made, the 
latest one (the one with the highest commentid) had commentid 2462203 
(mid = "max id").

Now, for each result, I want to know: has someone made a comment after 
I made my last comment?

For the selected result above, this means: are there any comments for 
the pearlsbeforeswine strip dated 2007-11-28 whose commentid exceeds 
2462203?

Of course, I can write a query for that one special case:

```
 
db.comments.find( 
{strip:"pearlsbeforeswine",yy:"2007",da:"28",mo:"11", 
commentid: {$gt: "2462203"}} 
).pretty()
```

but how do I do it for all the results in the resultset without 
creating an individual query for each one (even automated, that seems 
ugly).

Is this a poor use case for MongoDB? I have a similar (not identical) 
SQLite3 database where this query is:

```
 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT strip,month,date,year,MAX(id) AS mid FROM 
comments WHERE commentorid=801127 GROUP BY strip,month,date,year) AS t 
JOIN comments c ON (t.strip=c.strip AND t.month=c.month AND 
t.date=c.date AND t.year=c.year AND c.id > t.mid)
```

(where 801127 is my commentorid [the SQLite3 version doesn't include 
"commentor" name field]).

NOTE: My MongoDB commentid's are strings, not ints. That's bad, but I 
don't think it impacts this question.

Comment: you don't have a unique identifier for a specific strip in the comment?  Just combination of strip-yy-mo-da?  (I guess filename is a unique identifier but it seems hacky)...

Comment: No, I don't, but I suppose I could create one (the filename isn't unique, there are 20 comments per filename). Is MongoDB bad with multifield indexes? Would creating a "strip-yy-mo-da" field help? I assume MongoDB doesn't have views and/or creating "strip-yy-mo-da" as a virtual field wouldn't help?

Comment: see my answer - first project phase is just to merge the name into a unique strip identifier mainly to simplify the syntax further down.  Was just wondering what the reason was for not having a strip-yy-mm-dd type of field.  doesn't have to be unique - binning is a good answer to these types of schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the aggregation framework and there are multiple approaches towards this.  The simplest one is somewhat brute-force and long - it may not have the best performance but I think it's simplest to understand:

```
proj={"$project": {
        "strip" : {"$concat" : ["$strip","-","$yy","/","$mo","/","$da"]},
    "commentor" : 1,
    "commentid" : 1
     }
};

group={"$group": {
    "_id" : "$strip",
    "comms" : {
        "$push" : {
            "c" : "$commentor",
            "i" : "$commentid"
        }
    },
    "max" : {
        "$max" : "$commentid"
    }
}};

match = { "$match" : { "comms.c" : "<commentorname>" } };
unwind = { "$unwind" : "$comms" };

proj2 = { "$project" : {
        "meLast" : {"$cond" : [
            {"$eq" : [
                    "$max",
                    "$comms.i"
                ]
            },
            1,
            0
        ] }
    }
};
group2 = {"$group" : {
"_id" : "$_id",
"afterMe" : {
    "$max" : "$meLast"
}
} };

match2 = { "$match" : { "afterMe" : 0 } };

db.comments.aggregate( proj, group, match, unwind, match, proj2, group2, match2 );
```

Basically, whichever way you do it, there are two `{$group}` steps in the pipeline that you must have, one to find max commentid for this particular commentor and one for over max commentid for that strip.  So it could have been project, group, group, unwind, project with matches as appropriate.  Hope you get the idea.

By the way, if you had a unique identifier of each strip (say "comicId") you could then get the list of comics a particular person commented on much simpler, and then you don't need aggregation as much you could just use:

```
db.comments.distinct("comicId",{commentor:"name"})
```

which would significantly reduce the number of comments that need to be aggregated.  A simpler way to track conversations/replies may be to have comments have "in-reply-to" but then I'm not sure if you are tracking threaded conversations or just straight comments.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up adding indexes and getting my SQLite3 db to do this. I looked into MongoDB after 1) SQLite3 was too slow with this query, and 2) hoping to find a better solution for read-only databases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an excellent question and answer to the problem so I decided to solve this using Spring Data with MongoDB in java. To convert Asya's answer into java mongodb code, I did the following:

```
  public void commentTest() {

    BasicDBObject o1 = new BasicDBObject();
    o1.append("c", "$commentor");
    o1.append("i", "$commentid");
    Aggregation aggCount = newAggregation(
            project("commentid", "commentor")
                    .andExpression("concat(\"$strip\",\"-\",\"$yy\",\"/\",\"$mo\",\"/\",\"$da\")").as("strip"),
            group("strip").push(o1).as("comms").max("commentid").as("max"),
            match(Criteria.where("comms.c").is("Simon")),
            unwind("comms"),
            match(Criteria.where("comms.c").is("Simon")));
    logger.info(aggCount.toString());
    AggregationResults<CommentTest> groupCount = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggCount, "commenttest", CommentTest.class);
    List<CommentTest> resultCount = groupCount.getMappedResults();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        logger.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(resultCount));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then to get mongotemplate to parse the results successfully into the `CommentTest` class, I had to create the class that minicks the results:

```
Document(collection = "commenttest")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CommentTest {

    private String id, body, commentid, commentor, commentorid, da, filename, mo, strip, stripname, time, yy, max;
    @JsonProperty
    private comms comms;

    public CommentTest.comms getComms() {
        return comms;
    }

    public void setComms(CommentTest.comms comms) {
        this.comms = comms;
    }

    public static class comms implements Serializable {
        private String c,i;

        public String getC() {
            return c;
        }

        public void setC(String c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public String getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public void setI(String i) {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getCommentid() {
        return commentid;
    }

    public void setCommentid(String commentid) {
        this.commentid = commentid;
    }

    public String getCommentor() {
        return commentor;
    }

    public void setCommentor(String commentor) {
        this.commentor = commentor;
    }

    public String getCommentorid() {
        return commentorid;
    }

    public void setCommentorid(String commentorid) {
        this.commentorid = commentorid;
    }

    public String getDa() {
        return da;
    }

    public void setDa(String da) {
        this.da = da;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getMo() {
        return mo;
    }

    public void setMo(String mo) {
        this.mo = mo;
    }

    public String getStrip() {
        return strip;
    }

    public void setStrip(String strip) {
        this.strip = strip;
    }

    public String getStripname() {
        return stripname;
    }

    public void setStripname(String stripname) {
        this.stripname = stripname;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getYy() {
        return yy;
    }

    public void setYy(String yy) {
        this.yy = yy;
    }

    public String getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(String max) {
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

I then created some test data in mongodb by inserting these 4 mock entries:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518f14e5394594efbe18068c"), "body" : "1", "commentid" : "2525923", "commentor" : "Simon", "commentorid" : "769338", "da" : "25", "filename" : "/mnt/sshfs/gocomics/comments/100.out.bz2", "mo" : "11", "strip" : "luann", "stripname" : "Luann", "time" : "1 day ago", "yy" : "2011" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518f14e5394594efbe18068d"), "body" : "2", "commentid" : "2525924", "commentor" : "Josh", "commentorid" : "769339", "da" : "25", "filename" : "/mnt/sshfs/gocomics/comments/100.out.bz2", "mo" : "11", "strip" : "luann", "stripname" : "Luann", "time" : "1 day ago", "yy" : "2011" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518f14e5394594efbe18068e"), "body" : "3", "commentid" : "2525925", "commentor" : "Peter", "commentorid" : "769340", "da" : "25", "filename" : "/mnt/sshfs/gocomics/comments/100.out.bz2", "mo" : "11", "strip" : "luann", "stripname" : "Luann", "time" : "1 day ago", "yy" : "2011" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518f14e5394594efbe18068f"), "body" : "old1", "commentid" : "2525905", "commentor" : "Peter", "commentorid" : "769340", "da" : "24", "filename" : "/mnt/sshfs/gocomics/comments/100.out.bz2", "mo" : "11", "strip" : "luann", "stripname" : "Luann", "time" : "1 day ago", "yy" : "2011" }
```

I then ran the code and here are the results:

```
[{"id":"luann-2011/11/25","max":"2525925","comms":{"c":"Simon","i":"2525923"}}]
```

The result can be interpreted as post `luann-2011/11/25` has the maximum comment number (or mongo id) as `2525925` while your comment has an id of `2525923`. Therefore there is a later comment after you had comment hence you will need to fetch that new comment. You will need to write your logic for it programmatically.